# Searching in a dynamic array

Tags: c, arrays, search

I was trying to read  N numbers from a file FILE1 into an array
then sort those numbers;then search for numbers (1 per line, given in FILE2) in the array For each input number.

But when i am running this code its gives "segmentation falut". Please help me to correct this code.
heres my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
 int size=32;
 int main(int argc,char* argv[])
 {

     FILE *fp1=fopen("myFile1.txt","r");
     if (fp1 == NULL)
     {
            printf("cannot open this file");
            exit(0);
     }
    FILE *fp2 = fopen("test1.txt", "w");
    if (fp2 == NULL) 
    {
         printf("cannot open this file");
         exit(0);
    }
    FILE *fp3=fopen("myFile2.txt","r");
    if (fp3 == NULL)
    {
            printf("cannot open this file");
            exit(0);
    }
    int i=0,k,j,l,num,temp,m,c,d,Y,l1,u,mid,X,Z;
    int *B;
    int *C;
    int n;
    B= malloc(sizeof(int)*size);
    while(fscanf(fp1,"%d",&num)==1)
   {
         if(i<size)
        {
            B[i]=num;
            i++;
        }  
        else
        {
             C = malloc(sizeof(int)*2*size);
             for(m=0;m<size;m++)
             {
               C[m]=B[m];
             }
             free(B);
             size=size*2;
             B=&C[0];

        }

}

for(j=0;j<size;j++)
{
    for(l=0;l<size-1;l++)
    {
        if(B[l]>B[l+1])
        {
            temp=B[l];
            B[l]=B[l+1];
            B[l+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}
for(j=0;j<size;j++)
   fprintf(fp2,"%d  ",B[j]);


Y=0;
while(fscanf(fp3,"%d",&X)==1)
{
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)
  {
             if(B[i]==X)
            {
                 Y=1;
                 Z=i+1;
                 break;
            }
            else
            {
                if(X<B[i])
                {
                    Z=i+1;
                    Y=0;
                    break;
                }
                if(X>B[n-1])
                {
                    Z=n;
                    Y=0;
                    break;
                }
           }
   }

   if(Y==1)
        printf("number %d found at %d",X,Z);
      else
      printf("number not found");
  }


  return 0;
  fclose(fp1);
  fclose(fp2);
  fclose(fp3);
```

}

Comment: I can't be sure, but it looks like you might be trying to access `B` after you called `free(B);`. You can find out which line cause the segfault using GDB; compile using `gcc -g main.c -o program`, then load your program into GDB using `gdb myprogram`. At the GDB prompt, do `run`. After the seg fault type `bt`, and you will see a call trace for the line which caused the seg fault.

Answer (score 0):

You never **initialize 'n'** variable and make some stuff with.
Just put it in **unsigned int n = 0** to be sur is positive and 0 at the begin of your program and set it otherwise for loop will never be used:

`int i=0,k,j,l,num,temp,m,c,d,Y,l1,u,mid,X,Z;
    int *B;
    int *C;
    unsigned int n = 0;//here`

I hope that can help you,

Comment: now there is no segmentation fault,but it always print-"number not found".

Comment: In your request you say "File 1 and File 2" but you have 3 files opened ! Why do you use this third file ? In fact, you must try to factorise your code in function and use clear variable name. You will better understand your program. I can't help because i don't know what you have in files et why size = 32 etc. You can find the problem alone easily if clean your code. try to put some debug print if the time isn't at your side. I think i've resolved the question ;) good luck !